# Java web app interacts with a COM component in users local machine

Tags: java, applet, java-native-interface

We are planning to use Java Applet which will be downloaded to users browser and communicate with the com component using JNI. And also the applet will interact with the web page using Java Script.

Web page -> Javascript -> Applet -> JNI - > COM

The web page would display the data returned by the COM and also It can send the data back to the COM.

I wonder the experts here can point me to a right direction and suggests a better approach than this.

Thanks in advance,
Ramesh

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to work with a MS COM object (ActiveX) then I suggest to take a look at [JACOB](http://danadler.com/jacob/). That's a bridge from java to COM. There are also other libraries out there that might help you, guess it depends on what you want to do. It won't be easy anyway.

You also have to get out of the applet sandbox to be allowed to do these things. Use a certificate for that.

I wouldn't know how to interact with javascript from an applet though.

Comment: Thanks Albert for your response. 

Ok, to be more specific it is Quickbooks SDK. There is a web connector app from QB which needs to be installed and configured on every user's machine to share the QB (desktop version)data with any web based app. We don't to do that for some business reason. So I just wanted the experts here to validate my design.

Comment: #my comments on your suggestions

I'm not much bothered about the Java-Com bridge now, of course it's painful,but decided to use JNA which is platform independent.

I would be using signed applet. 

Javascript to Applet interaction is very much possible..http://java.polytechnic.edu.na/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html

Thanks again.